# $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n(\frac{2}{3})^n$ Evalute Sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3^{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1)

How can you compute the limit of 
$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n(2/3)^n$

Evidently it is equal to 6 by wolfram alpha but how could you compute such a sum analytically?

Comment: Hint:  For $|x|< 1$, try expressing $\frac{1}{1-x}$ as a series in $x$.  Then differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, and set $x = \frac{2}{3}$ in the new inequality.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r (In  particular, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/11549/) gives a more general result for _finite sum_

Comment: @user9352 Honestly I can't figure out what is the meaning of "Evidently it is equal to $6$ by Wolfram Alpha"... It seems like "software always got all the right answers" and the latter is a sound nonsense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(2/3)^n &=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty (2/3)^n \\ &=
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{(2/3)^m}{1-2/3} \\ &=
\frac{2/3}{(1-2/3)^2} = 6.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: +1. It may be worth to add, for clarity: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^n x^n = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=m}^\infty x^n$.

Comment: I think the indexing was off - it looked like you had a non-convergent inner sum.  I took the liberty of editing, but please check.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with power series.  If you let $f(x) := \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^n$ and restrict the domain of $f$ to the interval $|x|<1$ then 
$$\begin{align} f(x) &= x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} \\&= x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} x^n \\&= x\frac{d}{dx}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n) \\&= x \frac{d}{dx} \bigg( \frac{1}{1-x}\bigg) \\&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$
and substituting $x=2/3$ gives $f(x)=6$.

Answer (score 4):

Toss a coin that has probability $1/3$ of landing "heads" until we get a head.  Let $X$ be the number of tosses required.  We find the mean of $X$ in two different ways. Let our sum be $S$.

Note that $P(X=1)=1/3$, $P(X=2)=(2/3)(1/3)$, $P(X=3)=(2/3)^2(1/3)$, and so on. It follows that 
$$E(X)=1\cdot\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+ 2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+ 3\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+ 4\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\cdots.$$
Thus 
$$E(X)=\frac{1}{2}\left[1\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+ 2\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+ 3\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3+ 4\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4+\cdots\right]=\frac{S}{2}.$$

*If* the first toss is a head, then $X=1$. *If* that the first toss is a tail,  we have used up $1$ toss, and the game begins again. By the Law of Total Expectation,
$$E(X)=1\cdot\frac{1}{3} +(1+E(X))\cdot\frac{2}{3}.$$
Solve for $E(X)$. We get $E(X)=3$, and therefore $S=6$.

**Comment:** There is a very nice book on bijective arguments called *[Proofs that Really Count](http://books.google.com/books?id=FXLGzXwbwIAC)*. Maybe one should start collecting *Mean Proofs*.

Comment: very interesting, sometimes I wonder, how does this world looks in the eyes of people like yourself? It must be very different from my world! Also, thanks for naming the book.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem: We are both doing mathematics. I have been doing it a lot longer.

Comment: very humble-Thanks.

Comment: This made my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same as Mike's answer:

Let $$
\def\ts{\textstyle}
S_n=\ts{2\over3}+2( {2\over 3})^2 +3 ({2\over3})^3+\cdots+n ({2\over3})^n.$$

Then $$\eqalign{ 
\ts{2\over3}S_n
&=\ts \bigl[\,({2\over3})^2+2  ({2\over 3})^3+3 ({2\over3})^4
               +\cdots+(n-1) ({2\over3})^{n }\,\bigr]+n ({2\over3})^{n+1}\cr
&=\ts S_n-
[{2\over3}+ ({2\over3})^2 +({2\over3})^3 +    \cdots +  ({2\over3})^{n }  ] + n({2\over3})^{n +1} \cr
&=\ts S_n-{2/3 -(2/3)^{n+1}\over 1/3}+ n({2\over3})^{n +1}.
}$$

Whence

$$S_n={ {2/3 -(2/3)^{n+1}\over 1/3}- n({2\over3})^{n +1}\over 1/3}.$$

Taking the limit as $n$ tends to infinity gives
$$
S_n={2-0\over 1/3}=6.
$$

This method was observed ([for the general differentiated geometric series $\sum n r^n$](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=%20teaching%20tip%3A%20partial%20sums%20of%20the%20geometric%20series.&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flegacy.lclark.edu%2F~mathsci%2Fteachingtip.pdf&ei=5bvlTs-HMoLf0QGb9JSPBg&usg=AFQjCNFcLniG7xKvVjF-2URRpV_DwcaY5Q&cad=rja)) by Roger B. Nelsen, who has another lovely proof  [here](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/46/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=1860).

Comment: Also see this Math Stack Exchange answer which does what you are talking about for general $r$:  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/30741/6075

Answer (score 2):

I've read about doing it like this:

$y=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac23)^n$

$\frac23y=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty n(\frac23)^{n+1}=\sum \limits_{n=2}^\infty (n-1)(\frac23)^n=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)(\frac23)^n$, since $n=1$ yields $0$.

$y-\frac23y=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty [n-(n-1)](\frac23)^n$

$\frac13y=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty (\frac23)^n$

This sum you may be more familiar with.  If not, you can solve it similarly to obtain

$\frac13y=\frac{\frac23}{1-\frac23}=2$

$y=6$

Answer (score 0):

Just a curioursity.

Using Fourier series one comes to:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n\ \cos nx = 6\ \frac{13 \cos x-12}{(13-12\cos x)^2}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left( \frac{2}{3}\right)^n\ \cos nx \Bigg|_{x=0} =6\ \frac{13 \cos x-12}{(13-12\cos x)^2}\Bigg|_{x=0} =6\; .$$