# Finding the value of $\sum k/3^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3^{n+1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1)

please help me with this 
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k}{3^k}$$

I need just a hint, not a full answer. Thanks!

Comment: A hint? Sure! $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

Comment: A hint is to do $\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k$ first, then substitute $x=1/3$.  Is that enough?

Comment: A [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/what-is-the-limit-of-sum-limits-n-1-inftyn2-3n/90723) question. Also, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n3n1)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this.  One involves the fact that
$$
\frac{k}{3^k} = kx^k = x\cdot kx^{k-1} = x\cdot \frac{d}{dx} x^k
$$
where $x=1/3$, and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty x\cdot \frac{d}{dx} x^k$ can be found.

Another looks like this:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{k}{3^k} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{3^k}
= \left\{\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc} 
& & 1/3 \\
& + & 1/9 & + & 1/9 \\
& + & 1/27 & + & 1/27 & + & 1/27 \\
& + & 1/81 & + & 1/81 & + & 1/81 & + & 1/81 \\
& + & \cdots
\end{array}\right.
$$

Then you can sum the first **column**, then the second **column**, etc., and finally find the sum of all of the column sums.

Answer (score -4):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{kr^k}=\frac{r}{(r-1)^2}$$
In your case $r=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Quote: *I need just a hint, not a full answer*. Unquote.