# How to prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2^i}$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What would be the simplest way to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{i}{2^i}$ converges?

Comment: You can take the integration of $ \frac x{2^x}$ from 1 to $\infty $

Comment: Dear deeprog use the ratio test. $lim\frac{a_{i+1}}{a_{i}}=\frac{1}{2}$ as n approaches {\infty}$.

Comment: Partial sums are calculated in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129302/sum-of-the-series-sum-i-1n-i1-2i However, showing that a series converges is an easier task than finding its sum.

Comment: Here is another question about the same series: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441481/why-does-sum-n-0-infty-fracn2n-converge-to-2. And here is a generalization http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possible way : consider $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{i}{x^i}=x\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{i}{x^{i-1}}=x \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}{x^i}\Big)=x \frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{x}{1-x}\Big)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$ Now, replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{2}$ to get $2$.

The same procedure would apply to $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{i}{a^i}=\frac{a}{(a-1)^2}$$

Comment: This is precisely what occurred to me. +1 for you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

We have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1/n}}{2}=\frac{1}{2},$$
so by the Root Test our series converges.
The Ratio Test also works nicely.

Comment: Since your answer uses limit of $\sqrt[n]n$, I thought that it might be useful to add links to some posts about this limit: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28348/proof-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn-1/, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115822/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-n-frac1n-1

Answer (score 1):

One way is this:

1. Prove that for all $i\ge 1$, $i<(1.9)^i$.
2. Comparison test with $\sum \frac{(1.9)^i}{2^i}=\sum (\frac{1.9}{2})^i$, a convergent geometric series.