# Prove Finite Sum

Tags: summation

To prove (1)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac {i}{2^i} <2$$

Someone shows that (2)

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac {i}{2^i} =  2-\dfrac{n+2}{2^n}$$

so we can prove (1).

Can anyone guide me how from (1) they come up with (2) please ?
On what base they find (2) ?

Comment: What is $2_i$ ??? If it was meant $2^ i$, then search MSE, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129302/finite-sum-sum-i-1n-frac-i-2i?rq=1).

Comment: I assume your $2_i$ should be $2^i$. Work out the value of (2) for $n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ and guess the pattern.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde   it's 2^i

Comment: To answer the first question, finding the closed form solution for the LHS would be one of the simplest approaches to the problem if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

$$S:=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{2^i}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i-1}{2^i}+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{2^i}=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i-1}{2^{i-1}}+\frac{\dfrac12-\dfrac1{2^{n+1}}}{\dfrac12}\\
=\frac12\left(S-\frac{n-1}{2^n}\right)+1-\frac1{2^n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

First, we observe the trivial equality $i=\sum_{j=1}^i (1)$.  Using this, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{2^i}&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sum_{j=1}^i (1)}{2^i}\\\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i  \frac{1}{2^i}\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{i=j}^n \frac{1}{2^i}\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{(1/2)^j-(1/2)^{n+1}}{1-1/2}\right)\\\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^n (1/2)^j -2\sum_{j=1}^n(1/2)^{n+1}\\\\
&=2\left(\frac{(1/2)-(1/2)^{n+1}}{1-1/2}\right)-n(1/2)^n\\\\
&=2-(1/2)^n(n+2)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
S
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac i{2^i}
&&=\quad\frac 1{2^1}+\frac 2{2^2}+\frac 3{2^3}+\frac 4{2^4}+\cdots+\frac {n-1}{2^{n-1}}+\frac n{2^n}\tag{1}\\
2S
&= 
&&\frac 1{2^0}+\frac 2{2^1}+\frac 3{2^2}+\frac 4{2^3}+\frac 5{2^4}+\cdots  +\frac n{2^{n-1}}\tag{2}\\
(2)-(1):\hspace{3cm}\\
S
&=
&&\underbrace{\frac 1{2^0}+\frac 1{2^1}+\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 1{2^3}+\frac 1{2^4}+\cdots+\frac 1{2^{n-1}}}_{\text {GP:    }\ \ a=1,\ \  r=\frac 12}-\frac n{2^n}\\
&= 
&&\frac {\;\;1-\left(\frac 12\right)^n}{1-\frac 12}-\frac n{2^n}\\
&=
&&\color{red}{2-\frac {n+2}{2^n}}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac i {2^j}$. If you want to prove that $A<2$, this approach is natural: (i) you try to evaluate your sum; (ii) you take the difference from 2, and hope it is positive. In this case is a neat $\frac {n+2}{2^n}$, so it is good.

(Aside:) That the denominator is $2^n$, is clear. The real computation is the numerator. But you can convince yourself it is a linear polynomial, from the rate of convergence of the series $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac j {2^j}$.

(Extra:) I know it is not required in your question to prove (2), but for completeness I write up my favourite way of doing it. Consider the polynomial $1+x+\ldots+x^n=\frac {x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$. Take the derivative: $$1+2x+\ldots +nx^{n-1}=\frac{(n+1)x^n(x-1)-(x^{n+1}-1)}{(x-1)^2}.$$
Plug in $x=\frac 1 2$, multiply all by $\frac 1 2$, and you have it. Do you see how does the linear term $n$ appear in the numerator?  Whereas the main term $2=\frac 1 2 \frac {1}{(x-1)^2}$ is there because the other terms, that contain $x^n$, are typically very small, so they contribute to the "error term".