# Annuity-Due with Varying Payments (Arithmetics)

Tags: compound-interest

I need help to derivate a formula for the present value of an annuity with varying payments with the first payment being P at time = 0, and add a constant Q every increment of time.
$$P + (P+Q)v + (P+2Q)v^2+(P+3Q)v^3+ \dots + (P+(n-1)Q)v^{n-1}$$

A help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let your sum be $S$. Then $$S = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(P+kQ\right)v^{k} = P\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}v^{k} + Q \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}kv^{k}.$$

Now, we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}v^{k} = \frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v}$$
using the geometric series formula. Also from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1244351/643882), you can see that
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}kv^{k} = \frac{v-nv^{n} + (n-1)v^{n+1}}{(1-v)^{2}}.$$

Putting everything together, we have

$$\begin{align}
S &= P\cdot  \frac{1-v^{n}}{1-v} + Q\cdot \frac{v-nv^{n} + (n-1)v^{n+1}}{(1-v)^{2}}.
\end{align}$$