# Finding the sum of a series with an n term in the numerator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Sum the series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{7^{2n-1}}$$
I know it converges, but it's not a geometric series nor is it power/telescoping/alternating. I think having the n term in the numerator makes it difficult to solve.
I took calculus BC a number of years ago and I don't think I remember learning how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Essentially, you will find your answer here (look at the first answer, where the partial sum is computed) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn

Comment: $=14\sum\frac{n}{49^n}$.  [Alternative form of identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405332/how-to-calculate-sum-n-1-infty-n-an?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Actually, it *is* a power series, evaluated at $\frac17$

Comment: @saulspatz WolframAlpha says the answer is 0.298

Comment: @suzet - Thank you, will take a look at that

Comment: You misunderstand me.  I mean it's the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2nx^{2n-1}$ evaluated at $x=\frac17$

Answer (score 2):

For your specific problem, rewrite $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{7^{2n-1}}=2 \times 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{7^{2n}}=14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{49^{n}}$$ Now, consider 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}=x\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty  x^{n}\right)'$$

Finish and, when done, make $x=\frac 1 {49}$

Comment: You need to show that the derivative can be taken outside the infinite sum. To do this you need to first evaluate the partial sum (where taking the derivative works as it is a finite sum) and then take the limit. I've done this in my answer below.

Comment: @ChetanVuppulury: Any power series can be differentiated or integrated in the interior of region of convergence.

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. Can you give me a reference?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the geometric sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}a^n=\frac{1-a^N}{1-a}$. Then,
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}na^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}na^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}a^n=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}a^n=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\left(\frac{1-a^N}{1-a}\right)$$

Evaluating the derivative, we get
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\left(\frac{1-a^N}{1-a}\right)=\frac{\left(-Na^{N-1}\right)\left(1-a\right)-\left(1-a^N\right)(-1)}{\left(1-a\right)^2}=\frac{1-a^N-Na^{N-1}\left(1-a\right)}{\left(1-a\right)^2}$$

Thus,
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}na^{n-1}=\frac{1-a^N-Na^{N-1}\left(1-a\right)}{\left(1-a\right)^2}$$

As $N\rightarrow\infty$, we get

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na^{n-1}=\frac{1}{\left(1-a\right)^2}$$ for $|a|<1$. Now consider the series given.

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{7^{2n-1}}=\frac{2}{7}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{7^{2\left(n-1\right)}}=\frac{2}{7}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{49}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{2}{7}\times\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{49}\right)^2}=\frac{343}{1152}$$

So,
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{7^{2n-1}}=\frac{343}{1152}$$

This technique is widely used to evaluate sums and integrals in physics.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{7^{2n-1}}=2 \times 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{7^{2n}}=14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{49^{n}}$$

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n}{49^{n}}$ is convergent, which would be easily proven by  Cauchy radical test method. Hence, we may denote $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{n}{49^{n}}=\frac{1}{49}+\frac{2}{49^2}+\frac{3}{49^3}+\cdots. \tag1$$

Thus, $$49\cdot S=1+\frac{2}{49}+\frac{3}{49^2}+\frac{4}{49^3}+\cdots.\tag2$$

By $(2)-(1)$, $$48S=1+\frac{1}{49}+\frac{1}{49^2}+\frac{1}{49^3}+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{49}}=\frac{49}{48}.$$

Thus, $$S=\frac{49}{48^2}.$$

As a result, $$14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{49^{n}}=14 \cdot \frac{49}{48^2}=\frac{343}{1152}.$$