# Sum of infinite geometric series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How do I evaluate this (find the sum)? It's been a while since I did this kind of calculus.

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{i}{4^i}$$

Comment: Hint: Look at $f(x) = \sum \frac{ x^i }{4^i}$. Can you work out what $f(x)$ is in a simpler form? Now...what would $f'(x)$ be? And what would $f'(1)$ be?

Comment: HINT: Let $S = \sum_{i\geq 0} \frac{i}{4^i}$. Compute $4S$.

Comment: It's not a geometric series.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a duplicate of a … of a duplicate of a duplicate.

Comment: Some posts which are very similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proof-by-induction-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-r-1d-r-cdot-2r
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/what-is-the-limit-of-sum-limits-n-1-inftyn2-3n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn (@columbus8myhw Which question would you suggest as the duplicate target?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-1<x<1$, the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i$ converges absolutely to $\frac{1}{1-x}$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i=\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^{i-1} &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}ix^i&=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align*}
Now, by plugging $x=1/4$ into the last equation, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i}{4^i}=\frac{1/4}{(1-1/4)^2}=\frac{4}{9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i}{4^i}&=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^i}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{i}1\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=j}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^i}\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^j}\frac{1}{1-\frac14}\\\\
&=\frac{1/4}{(1-\frac14)^2}\\\\
&=\frac49
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me try.

Set $$S = \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{i}{4^i}.$$

Then we have $$4S = \sum_{i \geq 0} \frac{i+1}{4^i} = \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{i}{4^i} + \sum_{i\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^i} = S + \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}$$

So, $3S = \frac{4}{3}$. It implies that $$S = \frac{4}{9}.$$