# Calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+2)x^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I am trying to calculate   $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+2)x^n$.

I was thinking it is like the second derivative of $x^{n+2}/(n+1)$ but I am not sure how to go about calculating it. Any hints?

Comment: Shouldn't it be i

Comment: If it is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)x^n$, it may be easiest to write it as $\sum nx^n+\sum 2x^n$.

Comment: With a bit of searching you should be able to find many very similar questions on this site. Just a few:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proof-by-induction-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-r-1d-r-cdot-2r
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/what-is-the-limit-of-sum-limits-n-1-inftyn2-3n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$$

we know $$\sum_{n=0}^Nnx^n=-\frac{x(x^N-1)}{(x-1)^2}+\frac{Nx^{N+1}}{x-1}$$ and $$\sum_{n=0}^Nx^n=\frac {1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}$$

When $x\lt 1$ and $N \to \infty$ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)x^n=\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}+2\frac {1}{1-x}=\frac{2-x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! That's how I solved it based on Andre's hint.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You are on the right track, one may recall that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+2}}{n+1}=-x\ln(1-x),\quad |x|<1.
$$ Then differentiate termwise twice.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* It is sometimes convenient to work with *operators*. Since
\begin{align*}
\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n}
\end{align*}

we consider $xD:=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)$ as operator and obtain for $k\geq 0$
\begin{align*}
\left(xD\right)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^ka_nx^{n}
\end{align*}

> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)x^n&=\left(xD+2\right)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\\
> &=\left(xD+2\right)\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> &=x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^\prime+\frac{2}{1-x}\\
> &=\ldots
> \end{align*}