# Find closed formula by changing order of summation: $\sum_{i=1}^ni3^i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, exponential-function, closed-form, geometric-progressions

Working on homework for a probability and computing class, but my ability to work with summations is rusty to say the least, so I suspect this is going to turn out pretty straightforward.

Problem asks to find a closed formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^ni3^i$$ by representing it as a double sum and changing the order of summation. I did that by following a hint from the instructor and came up with $$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^n3^i,$$ but I'm not really sure what that accomplished. What's the next step? What am I looking for here?

Comment: Alternative: integrate with respect to 3

Comment: You can also have look at some similar sums and generalizations:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87030/proving-sum-limits-i-0n-i-2i-1-n1-2n-1-by-induction
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90637/sum-limits-n-1-inftyn-frac23n-evalute-sum
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn

Comment: And you can find a few other posts about similar sums [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5Eni3%5Ei%24&p=1).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a rather detailed elaboration which might be useful.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^ni3^i}&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^i 1\right)3^i\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^i 3^i
> =\sum_{1\leq k\leq i\leq n}3^i
> =\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^n3^i\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}3^{i+k}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^n3^k\cdot\frac{3^{n-k+1}-1}{3-1}\tag{4}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(3^{n+1}-3^k\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}3^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n3^k\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}3^{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{3-1}-1\right)\tag{7}\\
> &=\frac{n}{2}3^{n+1}-\frac{1}{4}3^{n+1}+\frac{3}{4}\tag{8}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{n}{4}(2n-1)3^{n+1}+\frac{3}{4}}\tag{9}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we represent the factor $i$ as sum.
- In (2) we multiply out in the left-hand sum and write the index range somewhat more conveniently in the middle sum. We exchange the sums in the right-hand double-sum.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start from $i=0$.
- In (4) we apply the *[finite geometric summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.
- In (5) we do some simplifications.
- In (6) we multiply out and do some simplifications.
- In (7) we apply the *finite geometric summation* formula again.
- In (8) and (9) we do some more simplifications.

Comment: Looks like I'm really gonna need to do some review on the geometric summation formula, but otherwise this was pretty helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @lordgankoo: You're welcome! :-) I've adjusted the expression in (7) somewhat to better see the connection with the formula in (4). Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Just use a sum of the geometric series.

It's
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{3^k(3^{n-k+1}-1)}{3-1}=\frac{n3^{n+1}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{3(3^n-1)}{2}=\frac{2n3^{n+1}-3^{n+1}+3}{4}.$$

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding how you got even that first step. Where does the $3^i$ come from? How did the lower bound become $i=1$ again?

Comment: @lordgankoo $a_1=3^k$ in our progression. I fixed. It was typo.

Answer (score 3):

Because the other answer already discusses about computing $\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=k}^n 3^i$, here's another way to compute $\sum_{i=1}^n i3^i$

\begin{eqnarray}
S & = & \sum_{i=1}^n i 3^i \\
& = & 1.3^1 + 2.3^2 + 3.3^3 + \cdots + n.3^n \\
3S & = & \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space 1.3^2 + 2.3^3 + \cdots + (n-1).3^n + n.3^{n+1} \\
\end{eqnarray}

Therefore, on subtracting, we get
$$S - 3S = (3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 + \cdots + 3^n) - n.3^{n+1}$$
$$\implies -2S = 3\left(\frac{3^n-1}{2}\right) - n.3^{n+1} = \frac{(1-2n)3^{n+1}-3}{2}$$
$$\implies S = \frac{(2n-1)3^{n+1}+3}{4}$$

Answer (score 2):

The inner sum is a geometric series. It can be expanded as follows:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^n3^i=\sum_{k=1}^n(\sum_{i=k}^n3^i)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3^k-3^{n+1}}{1-3}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{3^{n+1}-3^k}{2}=\frac{n3^{n+1}}2-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n3^k$$

The rest should be pretty straight-forward.