# A different answer for a limit question

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left[\frac{e^{1/k}}{k^2}+\frac{2(e^{1/k})^2}{k^2}+\frac{3(e^{1/k})^3}{k^2}+ \dots  +\frac{k(e^{1/k})^k}{k^2}\right]$$

[(Here is a picture of the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f31bC.jpg)

I have doubt in that question (where he has used $e^{1/k}$)
My doubt is as $k \to \infty$, $1\over k$ should tend to zero therefore $e^{1/k } \to 1$, so ${e^{1/k}\over k^2}$ should tend to zero because denominator is very huge so all series will end to zero but this is not the answer, the answer is 1. My teacher has done it by AGP method with which he got answer 1
please explain..

Comment: Are you sure that this is a limit and not a series?

Comment: hey i added a picture of question are u able to see

Comment: The question in the image is **not** asking you to find the limit of a single term of the summation, but rather to find the limit of the sum of the terms in the expression.  You may **not** push the limit inside of the summation, evaluate the limit first, and sum the result.  Limit of sum of terms is not sum of limits of terms.

Comment: hey but according to sum of limit property limit of sums is equal to sum of limits

Comment: That is not true in general, especially when the number of terms being added depends on the variable that changes in size.  Consider the following:  $1 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\dots = (\underbrace{\frac{1}{n}+\dots+\frac{1}{n}}_{n~\text{times}})\neq (0+0+\dots+0)=0$

Comment: Finite sums, not infinite sums, consider $\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k$

Comment: oh!!! i think i got a bit idea

Comment: hey but i am substituting the value of k everywhere so the limit should exist ! like limit(x tends to 0) x^2+x  ..... when i am substituting limit everywhere i get correct answer but why not here

Comment: What is happening to some degree is that you are looking at $\lim_{x\to c} f(x,g(x))$ and you are trying to say that it should be $\lim_{x\to c} f(x,g(x))= f(x,\lim_{x\to c} g(x))$ which is incorrect.  The actual limit you are trying to calculate depends on more than *just* the terms being added.  Consider my earlier counterexample.  $1 = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \neq  \sum\limits_{k=1}^{ \color{red}{n}} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$.  You essentially pushed the limit *past* some of the other terms you were wishing to change, the red $n$ in this case.

Comment: Your summation:  $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{i(e^{1/k})^i}{k^2} \neq \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{red}{k}} \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{i(e^{1/k})^i}{k^2}$

Comment: What is AGP method?

Comment: Maybe you could first simply $e^{1/k}+2(e^{1/k})^2+\dots+k(e^{1/k})^k$ (you can use the formula derived in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r/11549#11549)). And then use limit on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac {e^{1/k}}{k^2}=0$ for the reason you stated.  Either your teacher is wrong or you have misunderstood.

Comment: But the question you asked does not correspond to what you show from the book.

Comment: Each term in the sum goes to zero, but as $k$ increases the number of terms increases.  JMoravitz' example is a simple one.