# How can I solve this sum? $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^{k-1}$

Tags: summation

How can I solve this sum?

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^{k-1}$

Is $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k2^{k-1}$ equals to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k * \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{k-1}$

Comment: The supposed equality $\sum_k a_kb_k=\sum_ka_k\sum_kb_k$ is not true, as you can check with simple examples

Comment: Do you know how to sum $\sum_k x^k$?

Comment: Yes $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{k} = \frac{x^{n+1} - 1}{x-1} $

Comment: Now try differentiating with respect to $x$

Comment: Hint?$$kx^{k-1}=\frac d{dx}x^k$$

Comment: Can I solve without derivative? I'm in elementary school

Comment: Elementary school! Well congrats on tackling a high school summation problem!

Comment: You have two questions here - the one in the title has the answer "No - it's false for $n=2$ (and indeed all $n>1$)", but the question of a closed form for the sum is quite different. Could you remove one of the questions from the question to make the title agree with the content?

Comment: See also this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PARTIAL SOLUTION:

Here is how you would solve it. Set the sum equal to a variable
$$S(n)=2^0+2*2^1+3*2^2+...+n*2^{n-1}$$
Then multiply both sides by $(1-2)$:
$$S(n)(1-2)=(1-2)(2^0+2*2^1+3*2^2+...+n*2^{n-1})$$
Distribute:
$$S(n)(1-2)=2^0+2*2^1-2^1+3*2^2-2*2^2+...+n*2^{n-1}-(n-1)*2^{n-1}-n*2^n$$
$$-S(n)=2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^{n-1}-n2^n$$
Can you take it from here?