# Show $\sum_{k = 1}^n (k+1)2^k = n2^{n+1}$ by mathematical induction.

Tags: calculus, induction

Show  $\sum_{k = 1}^n  (k+1)2^k = n2^{n+1}$ by mathematical induction.

I made my base case $n = 1$. So $(1+1)*2^1 = 1(2^1+1)$ and $4 = 4$, which is true.

My inductive hypothesis is assuming $n = m$, the summation between $k = 1$ to $ m$ of $(k+1)*(2^k) = (m)*2^{m+1}$.

I need to show that $n = m + 1$ is true. So I did the summation $k = 1$ to $m + 1$ of $(k+1)*(2^k) = (m+1)*2^{(m+1)+1}$. But, I am unsure of how to proceed from here.

Comment: To prove a statement of the form $\sum_{k=1}^nf(k)=g(n)$ by induction, it suffices to prove (i) $f(1)=g(1)$ and (ii) $f(n+1)=g(n+1)-g(n)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute the  formula $\sum  \limits_{r=1}^d r \cdot 2^r$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11464/how-to-compute-the-formula-sum-limits-r-1d-r-cdot-2r)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: it's a lovely set of answers to a related question, but none of them answers **this** question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **show** that $\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(k+1)2^k=(m+1)2^{m+2}$, presumably using the induction hypothesis that $\sum_{k=1}^m(k+1)2^k=m2^{m+1}$. I’ll get you started:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(k+1)2^k&=\sum_{k=1}^m(k+1)2^k+\left((m+2)2^{m+1}\right)\\
&\overset{(*)}=m2^{m+1}+(m+2)2^{m+1}\\
&=\ldots
\end{align*}$$

The starred step is where the induction hypothesis is used.

Comment: In the interest of saving your time and effort I recommend using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%20%3D%201%7D%5En%20%20(k%2B1)2%5Ek%24&p=1) before posting. Many time duplicates of a FAQ often end up deleted, and that tool often helps when the obvious search string contains LaTeX-code.

Comment: That is why you donvoted this answer?